# How to correctly view a restored DD (image-->partition) (Clonezilla) from an APFS filesystem?

Tags: mac, dd, clonezilla, apfs

Currently the partition which contains the restored image is unreadable by Windows..
So I attach that partition (inside the disk via USB) to a Mac computer and it  also DOES NOT show up ..
What am I doing wrong..?

Comment: Do you still have access to the original source drive? If so, it might be best to start over doing this 100% on macOS with Disk Utility. There's no way for us to know what you or the tools you used did wrong. Are you following instructions from someone who has successfully cloned an APFS partition using Clonezilla, or are you trying to blaze your own trail?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not currently have the source drive.. Clonezilla has stated that I have Cloned successfully and restored successfully, however I cannot find a guide atm regarding my DD clone (APFS) situation..

Comment: I can't speak to Clonezilla, but `dd` just blindly copies bytes, and knows nothing about disks or partitions. So if you used `dd` to copy all the bytes of an APFS partition to a file, and then used `dd` to copy those same bytes from that file to a partition on a different disk, the top two ways I could see that going wrong is if the new disk's partition was not marked as APFS in the disk's GUID Partition Table (GPT), or if the new disk's partition was not exactly the same size as the original source disk's partition was. Inspect your new disk's GPT entry for that partition.

Comment: @Spiff   "I could see that going wrong is if the new disk's partition was not marked as APFS".....     Clonezilla has not instructed me to mark a partition specific to the source filesystem first before cloning, I thought Clonezilla is able to do that automatically.. So you are basically telling me I did the process incorrectly, and my clone is useless?  ............  Clonezilla HAS ALSO NOT instructed me that the destination partition must be the same exact size as the source...  Please link me to a knowledge page or something... :/

Comment: @Spiff Please, I am waiting patiently for your reply :)

Comment: Don't panic. Check the GPT on the new drive, and see what type it says that partition is. If it's the wrong type, fix it.

Comment: @Spiff The Disk is MBR, and My windows is actually in it,  I have dedicated a partition inside that disk for this cloning purpose...

Comment: MBR is ancient and obsolete. Apple never bothered to register an MBR partition type ID for APFS. Only GPT has a way to record that a partition is APFS. You'll need to upgrade your partition table to GPT or do your restore on a different disk that is already GPT.

Comment: @Spiff Okay thanks, I will be attempting a new clone again  the right way..